# Printing log analytics dashboards comes up as a vertical half page. How do I print the full dashboard?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-dashboard

I have a log analytics dashboard that I am trying to print to pdf of a dashboard I have set up in Log analytics but the print preview is coming up as vertical half page. The left half comes up in the pdf but the right half does not.

If you look at the page under the print preview pop up you can see that something is likely messing up with css for print media queries or something, the dashboard has shrunk horizontally and a scrollbar is seen under the print preview pop up. The moment you close the print preview pop up the horizontal scroll bar in the dashboard vanishes and it comes up perfectly fine again in the browser.

I confirmed this behavior in Edge, Chrome and FF.

I was wondering if there is something I can configure / change to get this to work. Thanks in advance for your inputs / help on this.

[image: Print preview of dashboard showing half page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for the problem and possibly the cause of the problem. On inspecting the CSS loaded on the page, I found this in the print media queries loaded on the page

```
.fxs-printmaxwidth{max-width:750px}
```

and that about was the width at which the page was being cutoff vertically when printed.

I edited this inline in developer tools to

```
.fxs-printmaxwidth{max-width:2750px}
```

and I am able to take print to pdf and get the full page

I did this in Edge.